# Return cell error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a messaging application in swift. But I ran into an error while creating the custom tableview cells and I have no idea how to fix this. I created 2 custom cells and I'm checking in code which cell I have to use.

Code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let uidReference = ref.child("Users").child(uid!)

    uidReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]

            if message.Sender == dictionary["Username"] as? String {
                let cell = self.messagesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "otherMessageCell") as! OtherMessageTableViewCell

                let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]

                cell.sender.text = message.Sender
                cell.message.text = message.Message

                let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

                let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
                let uidReference = ref.child("Users").child(uid!)

                uidReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if(message.Sender! == dictionary["Username"]! as! String) {
                            cell.sender.textAlignment = .right
                            cell.message.textAlignment = .right
                        }else{
                            cell.sender.textAlignment = .left
                            cell.message.textAlignment = .left
                        }
                    }
                }, withCancel: nil)

                let usernameReference = ref.child("Usernames").child(message.Sender!)

                usernameReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        let uid = dictionary["UID"] as! String
                        let uidReference = ref.child("Users").child(uid)

                        uidReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                let imageLink = dictionary["Image Link"] as! String

                                cell.profileImage.loadImageWithURLString(urlString: imageLink)
                            }
                        }, withCancel: nil)
                    }
                }, withCancel: nil)

                return cell
            }else{
                let cell = self.messagesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "selfMessageCell") as! SelfMessageTableViewCell

                let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]

                cell.sender.text = message.Sender
                cell.message.text = message.Message

                let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

                let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
                let uidReference = ref.child("Users").child(uid!)

                uidReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if(message.Sender! == dictionary["Username"]! as! String) {
                            cell.sender.textAlignment = .right
                            cell.message.textAlignment = .right
                        }else{
                            cell.sender.textAlignment = .left
                            cell.message.textAlignment = .left
                        }
                    }
                }, withCancel: nil)

                let usernameReference = ref.child("Usernames").child(message.Sender!)

                usernameReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        let uid = dictionary["UID"] as! String
                        let uidReference = ref.child("Users").child(uid)

                        uidReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                let imageLink = dictionary["Image Link"] as! String

                                cell.profileImage.loadImageWithURLString(urlString: imageLink)
                            }
                        }, withCancel: nil)
                    }
                }, withCancel: nil)

                return cell
            }
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

The error that I'm getting is: Unexpected non-void return value in void function.

I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: You can't return a cell in an asynchronous closure; you need to return the cell in the main code of the function and merely configure the cell in the closure; or even better, retrieve all of your data earlier and simply and quickly return a configured cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`